# How can I know why my application using PostgreSQL 9, hibernate 4.3.5 and c3p0 is hanging?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, c3p0

I'm working on an application which is based on PostgreSQL 9, hibernate 4.3.5.Final, c3p0, Tomcat 7 and JDK 7.

Here is the c3p0 configuration:

```
hibernate.c3p0.min_size=5
hibernate.c3p0.max_size=20
hibernate.c3p0.timeout=1800
hibernate.c3p0.max_statements=50
```

After few hours of utilization, the application is hanging. All screen are frozen because it seemed like no new transaction to the database could be opened.

I did a kill -3 on the tomcat 7 process (there is a single app deployed) to see where all the threads are locked. Here's a part of the output:

```
"ajp-bio-8127-exec-274" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000001365000 nid=0x257b in Object.wait() [0x0000000045242000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1414)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:606)
    - locked <0x000000078567cb70> (a com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:526)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutAndMarkConnectionInUse(C3P0PooledConnectio
```

It's the same for all the http requests processes. So all requests are waiting indefinitly for an available connection in the pool.

We had a look at the postgres to see that 20 connections were opened (20 is the pool max size):

```
foobar=# select datname, usename, client_port, query from  pg_stat_activity where usename='foobar';
 datname | usename | client_port |  query
---------+---------+-------------+----------
 foobar  | foobar  |       52992 | ROLLBACK
 foobar  | foobar  |       52993 | ROLLBACK
 foobar  | foobar  |       52991 | ROLLBACK
 foobar  | foobar  |       52994 | ROLLBACK
 foobar  | foobar  |       52995 | ROLLBACK
 foobar  | foobar  |       36398 | ROLLBACK
 foobar  | foobar  |       36399 | ROLLBACK
 foobar  | foobar  |       36400 | ROLLBACK
 foobar  | foobar  |       51766 | ROLLBACK
 foobar  | foobar  |       56689 | ROLLBACK
 foobar  | foobar  |       56690 | ROLLBACK
 foobar  | foobar  |       39582 | ROLLBACK
 foobar  | foobar  |       39581 | ROLLBACK
 foobar  | foobar  |       39583 | ROLLBACK
 foobar  | foobar  |       39590 | ROLLBACK
 foobar  | foobar  |       39592 | ROLLBACK
 foobar  | foobar  |       39591 | ROLLBACK
 foobar  | foobar  |       41799 | ROLLBACK
 foobar  | foobar  |       36105 | ROLLBACK
 foobar  | foobar  |       36103 | ROLLBACK
(20 rows)
```

So, we configured the pool logs to DEBUG, and we can see statements like theses:

```
2014/07/09 05:24:40 DEBUG (BasicResourcePool.java:1747) trace trace com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@12c39c9e [managed: 19, unused: 4, excluded: 0] (e.g. com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@4fc04747)
```

They show that the managed connexion number grows slowly until managed: 20 and usused: 0 this final state remains stable and the application is frozen because all the threads are expecting a connection to be available from the pool.

It's a web application and we use the session in request pattern so the connection are closed properly after each request is processed (in a finally statement). There is no such thing like an ERROR or WARN in the application logs.

How can I know what did I do wrong ?

Comment: Can you please include the code you are using to open and close the connection? (not just the single lines, include some of the context where you're doing them)

Comment: It's a GPL-licenced software, you can check out the [source](https://svn.codelutin.com/wao/trunk), the try..finally statement is in this [class](https://svn.codelutin.com/wao/trunk/wao-web/src/main/java/fr/ifremer/wao/web/WaoInterceptor.java)

Comment: Well it doesn't seem the `try...finally` is surrounding everything that could go wrong. Its only around one line. What if an Exception happens in one of the lines from when you call `newServiceContext()` till where you have the `try`? Can `newServiceContext()` itself throw an unchecked Exception? What about the last line in the `else`, why doesn't it have a surrounding `try ... finally`? I would suggest surrounding as much as possible and also adding a `catch` clause so that if something wrong it happens there you would be able to log it.

Comment: @jbx the issue here is that nothing go wrong. There is no exception raised by the code above the `try` statement so that is not the problem. If an exception were thrown, I would have find it in tomcat logs. The last line (`else`) is not surrounded because it's an access to a static resource (css...) so not transaction required. But, **you are right** :) The problem is the `return "redirect-to-login"` statement, a `serviceContext` is created before (instead of after the `return`). Each time this `return` statement is called, a connection is left opened. Fix committed, we will see. Thanks :)

Comment: Nice good luck. However in such a case I would still make the code a bit clearer and surround the part where the connection is open with a `try... finally`. It makes the code clearer and if anyone else adds one line of code which could throw an Exception, even an unchecked one, you would still always close the connection... whether you want to add `catch` or not is another story.

Comment: That's what I did, now serviceContext is openend in the try clause. I will use a try-with-resources clause soon (see trunk).

Comment: Yes exactly, if you are using Java 1.7 or later, try-with-resources is the best way to do it, it was specifically designed for these kinds of situations. I would also check a bit the `newServiceContext()` method. Is there a risk that after you create the persistence context the line after that throws a `NullPointerException` or some other unchecked exception? You might want to separate resources that need to be explicitly closed from those that will just get garbage collected (like HTTP session objects etc.) and maybe bundle them together in a `WaoServiceContext` only when you are in the `try`

Comment: It's in production now. The issue is fixed. I'm still disappointed that i couldn't find the origin of the problem with a suitable tool. All bugs can't be found by re-re-re-reading the code... Thanks jbx

Answer (score 1):

Well evidently those queries are getting blocked without being released. It could be that you are getting some exception or something which you are not seeing, because the query is marked as `ROLLBACK`, and for some reason the thread is hanging waiting for the query to finish or something of that sort. Without seeing the code its difficult to say exactly.

What you could do is wait for this to happen again and then get a full thread dump. This should give you full details of where each thread is hanging, so you could see what the 20 connections are waiting on.

You can use [jstack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstack.html) for this, which comes with the JDK.

You could also enable JMX on Tomcat and connect to it using jconsole or jvisualvm to see in real time what the threads are doing.

Comment: as I said in the question, I already know where all the threads are hanging. There are all blocked on `com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable`. Using jconsole or jvisualvm will just give the exact same trace.

Comment: Well you should have 2 kinds of hanging threads. What you have shown so far are the threads which are hanging after the problem happens. Those are legitimately hanging because they are waiting for a connection to be available. The other types of threads (you should have 20) should be hanging somewhere else... unless you just have a place where you are not returning the connection. Are you sure all the places where you are obtaining a connection are surrounded by a `try ... finally` block, and you are closing the connection in the `finally`? Without an example of the code its difficult to say.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your application runs out of available pooled connections. A transaction is marked as rollback only if an exception was thrown. If you can't see any exception it might be because you don't properly handle them, like logging any exception with an ERROR threshold.

You need to check the db log as well, maybe you find what causes all those transactions to rollback.

Comment: I handle exceptions properly. My code style implies a strong **no empty catch clause** rule so I think no exception was raised ever. That's why the issue is so... annoying. Unfortunately, i don't have access to the production platform. Hope the admin will be able to give me the PG logs :-(